# Is there any possible way of safely stopping a Windows 10 update while in progress?

Tags: windows-10, boot, drivers, security

Unfortunately, I have begun a Windows 10 update, without the actual desire to do so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a Cancel button? If so you can cancel and wait. It it cannot be cancelled, then you must wait for it to complete. There is no other option.

Comment: I have seen that as well. It is completing a big update.

Comment: Windows 10 updates have to be allowed to finish if past the stage of cancelling

Comment: You mean the comment?  The only answer was submitted by John. This is one the reasons we don’t allow discussions in the comment section.

Comment: @ArtFowler If the update displays a cancel button, then that would roll back and remove the flag set by the update process.  Simply shutting off the PC won't help, as there will still be a flag set (to complex to explain in a comment) and Windows will auto-resume the update upon boot, likely before even allowing you to log in.  If it's a bi-annual update (i.e. 1809, 1903, 1909, etc.) you can roll back via Settings > Update & Security > Recovery > Go back to a previous version of Windows 10.  Once done and logged back in, clean up WinSxS: `dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup`